# How can I change location.href in child frame to relative path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

I'm doing some cross-domain JS things with two pages: `http://app.domain.dev` (main window) and `http://framed.p.domain.dev` (in the frame). On both pages `document.domain='domain.dev'` is executed before any manipulations.

Second page (framed) has a combobox with JS function bound to its 'change' event by using `onChange='cbChanged(this)'` on `select` HTML tag. The function looks like this:

```
function cbChanged(param){
    location.href = '/some/url?cbchanged'
}
```

When I change the combobox value manually, the location successfully changes to `http://framed.p.domain.dev/some/url?cbchanged`.

BUT when I try to send a change event from the parent window's JavaScript, the location changes with the parent domain basis: `http://app.domain.dev/some/url?cbchanged`. The problem shows up in Firefox and OS X Safari, but in Chrome everything works fine.

The parent page's code I use to send change event:

```
var frame = $('frame');
var combobox = frame.contents().find('.cb')[0];
var cw = frame.contentWindow;
cw.setTimeout(function(){
    cw.triggerEvent(combobox, 'change');
}, 0);
```

Here is the `triggerEvent` function from the child frame:

```
function triggerEvent(element, type) {
    jQuery(element).trigger(type);
}
```

---

So, I need to trigger the change event programmatically from the parent window. I want `location.href` to change relatively to the child domain and I want it to work in all modern browsers.

Content of the child frame is 3rd party and I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : 
    var iframe=document.getElemntById("someid");
    iframe.contentWindow.location.href="someurl";

Comment: I've read your question again . you can't ever access 3rd party iframes contents .

Comment: Look, I've noted that I execute `document.domain='domain.dev'` on both pages. Setting this domain is only thing I can do with 3pty page